# docker-compose build does not build properly

Tags: apache, docker, centos, ldap

First of all, i'm new to this docker thingy. It has been less than a month of me playing with docker.
I'm trying to build a set of containers using docker-compose. However, it does not build properly. I don't really know how to explain but i'll try my best with the description of my problems.

First of all, i got two container that use same image of Centos 7, therefore, i cannot use docker-compose up -d right off the bat. I need to run docker-compose build --pull --no-cache first.

But even though the build is complete, i've encountered some problems.

This is the docker-compose file:`<http://pastebin.com/xkMpBst4>`

These are the dockerfiles

Dockerfile:`<http://pastebin.com/SzXynB01>`

Dockerfileldap:`<http://pastebin.com/Q4Q8f1Vu>`

After running the docker-compose up -d, the site still cannot be accessed. The cause is, the user 3eadmin is not created. Though i already put "RUN useradd 3eadmin" inside the dockerfile. As for that, i need to access into the container and run useradd 3eadmin manually and restart the httpd. Only then i can access the site.

For the ldap, as you can see in the dockerfileldap, i've commented the script from runnning. Because the build will fail if that is not commented. as a result, everytime the container is down, i need to redo the step which is to rebuild the ldap entirely from beginning.

Can someone help me with my issues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `image: centos:7` from sso and ldap services in your compose file as you are specifying dockerfile and it is already based on Centos 7. Try again after that.

Comment: Hi Mr Rajesh. Thank you for the solution. It works. However, when i uncomment the line for running the script in dockerfileldap, it gave me this error https://imgur.com/a/6ND0FKd

Do you have any idea why? Even the command for creating password for pass.txt does nothing as the file is empty

Comment: You copied pass.sh to path /ldap/pass.sh using COPY ./ldap/pass.sh /ldap/pass.sh. You can run script using RUN /ldap/pass.sh.

Comment: i've tried using that. However, if i do that, it will show error as the slapd service was not started. Therefore, i need to do it manually by commenting the run  script and do exec into the container and run it there.

Comment: Can&#39;t you start that service before running pass.sh?

Comment: unfortunately cannot. something about systemd issue. https://imgur.com/a/CrgGcL7

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WYy8hiU4 this is my dockerfile. is there something wrong with it?

Comment: I would suggest trying to search for the cause of error irrespective of docker. May be that will help.